What is the function of a concave lens in a laser pointer?
In my cheap laser pointer I found a concave lens in front of the LED. I expected a convex lens. If I remove the concave lens the beam is much less collimated. The same if I replace the concave lens with a convex lens (from a DVD player).
Can anyone explain how the concave lens manages to collimate the beam more than a convex lens?

Is the concave lens one of a pair? Can you adjust the collimation of the pointer by moving the lens in or out?
A beam expander often in the form of a Telescpoe. Two designs are common - Keplerian and Galilean. See Does it matter whether a beam expander or reducer has a Keplerian or Galilean design?
It might be possible that the LED itself has a convex lens molded into it. In this case, the concave lens would be the second element of a beam reducer. This is a beam expander run backward.

Thanks for your answer. There is only this one concave lens visible. Indeed you can move it forwards and backwards by screwing its socket in order to adjust collimation.
If this works as a beam reducer shouldn't be the beam more collimated compared to removing the lens?
